# Trying to understand Java Classloading

Tags: java, classpath

I'm currently getting to know Java and OSGi, so I've read a few books. In one particular book the class loading is described.

You can download it (free and legal) from the authors page (Neil Bartlett):
[OSGi Book](http://njbartlett.name/blog/osgibook/)

On page 9 and 10 are this pictures:

[alt text http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/4127/picture1qct.png](http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/4127/picture1qct.png)[alt text http://img297.imageshack.us/img297/594/picture2yv.png](http://img297.imageshack.us/img297/594/picture2yv.png)

It seems like there is the possibility that our class "Foo" won't use the class "Bar" of foobar.jar, but instead class "Bar" from naughty.jar.

Because of the flat and global structure of the Java classpath this could be, but as far as I know you would define a package from where you want to import a certain class:

```
import foobar.Bar
```

This should prevent loading the wrong class, shouldn't it? Of course assuming that the package is called "foobar".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `import` statement has nothing to do with classloading - it just allows you to use short name `Bar` instead of the fully qualified `foobar.Bar`. If both `foobar.jar` and `naughty.jar` contain class with fully qualified name `foobar.Bar`, classloader will load the class from the from the first jar file with required class on the classpath.

Comment: Unless the package is sealed or has different signers.

Comment: Parent class loader delegation is an issue too, not just the class path. If naughty.jar is handled by a parent `ClassLoader` then the classes in it will always be resolved first (though a sealed package keeps this from happening as well).

Comment: Thank you for your answer axtavt. But this also means if the "Bar" class from  foobar.jar is in package "hello" (hello.Bar) and the "Bar" class from naughty.jar is in the package "evil" (evil.Bar) there won't be any problems? Since the fully qualified names are different. There only would be a problem if in both jars the package in which the "Bar" class is located would be the same?

Comment: @Jens: Yes, you won't have any problems if fully qualifiead names are different.

Answer (score 2):

good idea, but unfortunately packages are independent of the jar file names. you can have things in arbitrary packages all in the same jar file, and arbitrary jar file names with unrelated package names. it's up to the classloader to resolve them for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is both `foobar.jar` and `naughty.jar` might have a class that its fully qualified name is `foobar.Bar`. Then `foobar.Foo` resolves the `foobar.Bar` of `naughty.jar` instead of `foobar.Bar` of `foobar.jar`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The author is assuming here that both versions of the `Bar` classes are in the same package (or there wouldn't be any problem). What the author is describing can happen if naughty.jar is "first" in the class path. In that case, the classloader would pick the naughty version (the classloader scans the classpath in the natural order and picks the first class found).

Answer (score 0):

The import doesnt allow you the liberty of loading the class from the desired java. You can read more about classloaders from here [Java Classloaders](http://technologiquepanorama.wordpress.com/2009/01/13/java-classloaders/)